# What is the origin of skinflint and the image it is derived from

Tags: etymology

I would like to know what's the origin of the word skinflint.

When you lookup skinflint in a dictionary you will find a definition like the following:

```
A penurious person; a miser; a person who is stingy with money; a penny-pincher.
```

I can easily imagine what a penny-pincher literally describes but what's the image or action a skinflint is derived from?

I found on [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/skinflint) the following description:

> slang; literally "kind of person who would skin a flint to save or
>   gain something"

But it's still unclear to me.

Has it to do with the knapping off flint flakes or the scraping of animal skins with a flint?

Comment: In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcMgmoYDlrM) the origin is explained as to "use the flint so many times that it becomes as thin as skin". That sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skinflint is an old expression, probably  from thieves slang,   whose meaning suggested the idea that one would even skin a flint to save something of it.

> The noun ***[skinflint](https://wordhistories.net/2017/09/20/origin-of-skinflint/)***, which denotes a niggardly person, is first recorded in A New Dictionary of the Terms Ancient and Modern of the Canting Crew (London, 1699), by “B. E. Gent.”:
>
> - *Skin-flint, a griping, sharping, close-fisted Fellow.*
>
> ***It is from the hyperbolical phrase to skin a flint, denoting excessive meanness or the willingness to go to extreme lengths to save or gain something.***
>
> This is comparable to the French phrase tondre un œuf (to shave an egg), which used to be tondre sur un œuf (to shave on an egg); Randle Cotgrave defined it in A Dictionarie of the French and English Tongues (1611):
>
> *Tondre sur vn oeuf. To accuse truth of falsehood, charge vertue with vice, find a fault where there is none; also, to make a commoditie of any thing, how bare soeuer it be; whence, Ils trouveront à tondre sur vn oeuf (= They will find [something] to shave on an egg).*
>
> ***The phrase to skin a flint is first recorded in one of the poems introducing the 1656 edition (London) of The Legend of Captain Jones***. Relating His adventure to Sea: His first landing, and strange Combat with a mighty Bear.
>
> *This were but petty hardship, Jones was one*
>
> *Would Skinne a Flint, and eat him when h’had done.*

(Wordhistories.com)

Lexicographer Craig M. Carver suggests that the idea skinning a flint  may derive from riflemen:

> [The flint in skinflint](https://www.bozemandailychronicle.com/go/words/word-of-the-week-skinflint-from-thrifty-riflemen/article_e01cd35f-c503-5a4b-8ccb-18ac39cff795.html) is the hard stone used to spark fires when struck with iron or steel. Craig M. Carver, lexicographer and managing editor of the Dictionary of American Regional English writes about flint and its role in riflery, and how this inspired the word “skinflint”:
>
> - *[The rifle] used a piece of flint held in a hammerlike device, or “cock.” When the trigger was pulled, the spring-loaded cock struck the flint against a steel plate… creating a shower of sparks. The flash of the priming powder in the pan just beneath the steel plate ignited the charge in the bore and fired the weapon... After repeated firings, the flint wore down. Most riflemen merely replaced the flint, but some penny-pinchers “skinned” or sharpened their flints with a knife.*

(www.bozemandailychronicle.com)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, in a modern context the word does *not* imply ill-temper or meanness (as some dictionaries may state).

Current usage of the word is more along the lines of someone who is habitually or foolishly cheap. e.g. Unwilling to spend a bit more money now, yet *knowing* it could be much more costly in terms of grief and/or expenses in the future.

"One who is very reluctant to spend money even when it is clearly in one's best interest."

Comment: References would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like this one from freedictionary.com
By
skinflint - A miser, penny pincher, tightwad; a mean, avaricious, niggardly person. This term is derived from the earlier to skin a flint which was based on the idea that only an excessively rapacious person would even attempt to remove and save the nonexistent skin of a rock such as flint. One source recounts the tale of an Eastern caliph who was so penurious that he issued his soldiers shavings that he had “skinned” from a flint to save the cost of their using complete flints in their rifles.